# Symfony Doctrine Date Infinity

Tags: symfony, doctrine

How can I make Doctrine accept `infinity` as a valid date value?

I've already tried adding to the `config.yml`

```
dbal:
    mapping_types:
        infinity: string
```

and

```
dbal:
    types:
        infinity: string
```

But to no avail, it doesn't work.

Doctrine throws an exception with a message of:

> Could not convert database value "infinity" to Doctrine Type date. Expect format: Y-m-d

I'm using Symfony 2.7 PHP 5.6.31

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doctrine  does not support platform specific functions you should use a custom mapping type or manage it.

example:

```
class DateTimeType extends Type {
    public function convertToPHPValue($value, AbstractPlatform $platform)
    {
        if ($value=='infinity' || $value=='-infinity') {
             /manage it
        }

        //other code
    }
}
```

Comment: will this affect the way Doctrine currently treat my date column? I need infinity because it's a value for a special case in a date column. Sorry to bother you.

Comment: you need to create a custo type or manage it into doctrine vendor or overwrite that class, because doctrine can't do it.
It doesn't change how treat date, only you need to manage infinity @Wreigh